# forEach to access Firestore docs

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

In this example the first text widget returns the error "Column's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 0."

But if I comment it out, the second text widget returns the title of the document at the 0 index.

(I'm using Streambuilder and Firestore)

Why?

```
Column(
            children:[
              snapshot.data.docs.forEach((e) {
                return Text('${e['title']}');
              
              }),
              Text('${snapshot.data.docs[0]['title']}'),
            ]
```

Comment: ```forEach``` has void as return type. You can't return from ```forEach```, use ```.map``` instead to transform your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a different between `forEach()` and `map()`. `forEach()` returns `undefined` while `map()` returns an array.

`forEach()` is usually used when handling data from the APIs or applying a function without having to write a loop explicitly. In this case, it's more suitable to use `map()` to return a list of widgets. You can do this:

```dart
Column(
   children:
       List<Widget>.from(snapshot.data.docs.map((e)=> Text('${e['title']}'))),
),
```

It would, by the way, be better to transform your data into a `Model` before using it within the UI. For example you have a json object:

```json
// A list of json objects
[
   {
      "title":"Sample title1",
      "content":"Sample content"
   },
   {
      "title":"Sample title2",
      "content":"Sample content"
   }
]
```

You can then define a class for that object:

```
class Post {
  final String title;
  final String content;

  Post({this.title, this.content});

  fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      title: json['title'],
      content: json['content'],
    );
  }
}
```

Then parse the json and use it in the UI:

```dart
// `data` is the list of json objects
var posts = List<Post>.from(data.map((json) => Post.fromJson(json)));

// In the UI
Column(
  children: List<Widget>.generate(
    posts.length,
    (index) => Text(posts[index].title),
  ),
)
```

With the `Stream` from Firebase, you can do something like:

```dart
  Stream entryStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    entryStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('entries').snapshots();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: entryStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
            var fbEntries = List<Entry>.from(
                snapshot.data.docs.map((json) => Entry.fromJson(json)));
            return Column(
              children: List<Widget>.generate(
                fbEntries.length,
                (index) => Text(fbEntries[index].title),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Bach! Super helpful. I originally wrote the app using models but when I started trying to implement Firestore I became lost. I haven't wrapped my head around the  json parsing yet.

Comment: The parsing can become quite complicated (multi level of object within object) depends on the json object's structure. I'd say it'll be easier to have a max 2 levels of depth for a json object for data handling at the app level. You can use this site to create a Model quickly from a json object: https://app.quicktype.io/ (choosing Dart as the target language)

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to articulate this, but here I try...I've defined my class <Entry> to include .fromJson() method as you suggested, but I'm not sure how to utilize Streambuilder with (in your example) the var posts. The 'data' in 'posts' is the list of json objects as you indicated, but it's incoming as a stream from Firebase. Therefore I'm trying to tie the stream to the 'data' doing something like this: `var fbEntries = List<Entry>.from(FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('entries').snapshots().data.docs.map((json) => Entry.fromJson(json)));` Am I even on the right track?

Comment: @CoreyStewart Yes you're on the right track, just need to put the `Stream` from Firebase into correct use. I've updated my answer above for your reference

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @danypata

This is how you should transform your list.

```dart
Column(
   children:List<Widget>.from(
       snapshot.data.docs.map((e)=> Text('${e['title']}'),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but I get the error type List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Widget when using your solution.

I found that if I use the spread operator in front of snapshot it works then.

Comment: I updated the answer, in short, you need to convert the List<dynamic> to List<Widget>